# Xamarin UI Test Inconsitent Results

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

We are currently running a set of 26 tests. However when running in App Center we are getting inconsistent results.

These are all running off the same codebase. And it always seems to be the same tests that are sometimes failing.

[image: Test Results]

We are using x.WaitForElement and a TimeSpan of 10 seconds,

```
 ApplicationContext.WaitForElement(x =>
           x.Property("Text")
           .Contains(element),
           timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Description of error:

```
System.Exception : Error while performing WaitForElement(Property("Text").Contains("Services"), "Timed out waiting for element...", 00:00:10, null, null)  
----> System.TimeoutException : Timed out waiting for element...  
at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] func, System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) [0x0005b] in <b407387d5472492e9a5a9fb5ff2a9418>:0   
at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp.WaitForElement (System.Func`2[T,TResult] query, System.String timeoutMessage, System.Nullable`1[T] timeout, System.Nullable`1[T] retryFrequency, System.Nullable`1[T] postTimeout) [0x00032] in <b407387d5472492e9a5a9fb5ff2a9418>:0   
at Cashoo.AutomationTests.Base.BasePage.WaitForAnElementToPresent (System.String element) [0x00036] in <86d386ec5946400cb6c19f52c8ea595c>:0   
at Cashoo.AutomationTests.TestsPerPage.DashboardPageTests.ClickOnChooseCashback_ReturnsServicesPage () [0x00016] in <86d386ec5946400cb6c19f52c8ea595c>:0  
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)  
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0 --TimeoutException  
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.WaitForHelper.WaitForAny[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] query, System.String timeoutMessage, System.Nullable`1[T] timeout, System.Nullable`1[T] retryFrequency, System.Nullable`1[T] postTimeout) [0x0001d] in <b407387d5472492e9a5a9fb5ff2a9418>:0   
at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp+<>c__DisplayClass86_0.<WaitForElement>b__0 () [0x00054] in <b407387d5472492e9a5a9fb5ff2a9418>:0   
at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] func, System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) [0x0000e] in <b407387d5472492e9a5a9fb5ff2a9418>:0
```

Any Ideas will be gratefully appreciated.

Extra Info:

1) Xamarin.UiTest v2.2.5

2) Android v7.1.2

3) Code snippet:

```
//CTOR
public DashboardPageTests(Platform platform)
{
        this.platform = platform;
        ApplicationContext = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
        phoneNumberPage = new PhoneNumberPage();
        passwordPage = new PasswordPage();
        phoneNumberPage.EnterPhoneNumberAndClick("07510000000");
        passwordPage.EnterPasswordAndClickSignIn("A123456a");
}

[Test]
public void ClickOnChooseCashback_ReturnsServicesPage()
{
    //Act
    ApplicationContext.WaitForElement(x =>
       x.Property("Text")
       .Contains("Dashboard"),
       timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    dashboardPage.ClickOnChooseCashback();
    ApplicationContext.WaitForElement(x =>
       x.Property("Text")
       .Contains("Services"),
       timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    var elementPresent = ApplicationContext.Query("Services");
    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(elementPresent.Any(), "Services text is not visible.");
    servicesPage.ClickOnBackButton();
}
```

Comment: A few questions :) (1) What version of UITest are you running? (2) What version of Android is the test running on? (3) Can you share what's happening before this `WaitFor` method? The whole test code would be useful. Also - I would advise (if you haven't already) reaching out to the support guys on Intercom (it's the little speech bubble on the bottom right in your App Center portal).

Comment: Extra info added to main question.
I have just sent a message on App Center, didn't realise that was there so thanks!

Comment: No problem, I work on the App Center Test team so your support request may get round to me eventually :) What does the element that you're looking for look like?

Comment: One thing I would try is adding a Screenshot call at the start of the test for debugging so you can see what the state of the app is like when you get these errors. Maybe you have a timing issue in your constructor?

Comment: In our project with almost 200 UI tests we also experience this behavior: The UI tests run and pass when executed locally but on AppCenter they fail for odd reasons.